# simple latex table using tabularx--error?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I wanna create a simple LaTeX table. Since I have created a more complex table using `tabularx`, I decided to just cut and paste the codes. But why the error? Thx for any help^^

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{}

\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{tabularx} {20.3cm} {@{} l Y @{}} \\
\arrayrulecolor{blue} 

\toprule[0.14em]
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Description} \\
\cmidrule(l{.75em}){1-1} \cmidrule(l{.75em}){2-2}   
 STI_30 & Member of the STI Index \\
 CPFIS  & CPF Investment Scheme \\
 Produce_Full_SR & Produce Full Sustainability Report \\
 Full_SR_Assured & External Audit of Full Sustainability Report \\
 Sus_Sec_in_AR & Sustainability Section in Annual Report provided \\
 Sus_Sec_Assured & External Audit of Sustainability Section in Annual Report \\
 GRI & Compliance with Global Reporting Index \\
 Materiality & Materiality of Disclosure \\
 Has_Sus_Efforts & Has Sustainability Efforts \\
 C_or_S & Stewardship in Sustainability Efforts in general \\
 Water_Efforts & Has Water Efforts \\
 C_or_S1 & Stewardship in Water Conservational Efforts \\
 \midrule
 EnergyD & Energy Disclosure \\
 EmissionsD & Emissions Disclosure \\
 WasteD & Waste Disclosure \\  
 WaterD & Water Disclosure \\
  FullD & Full Disclosure (Energy, Emissions, Waste, Water) \\
 AnyD & At Least One the Four Disclosures \\

\bottomrule[0.14em]
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par

\normalsize
\end{center}

\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem here are the underscores (`_`) that indicate subscripts and go into mathematical mode (hence the error message with the `$`) , a way to solve it is to place a backslash  in front of the underscores so `\_`

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following corrected and reduced code. I masked your used `_` with `\_`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{}

\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{tabularx} {20.3cm} {@{} l Y @{}} \\
\arrayrulecolor{blue} 

\toprule[0.14em]
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Description} \\
\cmidrule(l{.75em}){1-1} \cmidrule(l{.75em}){2-2}   
 STI\_30 & Member of the STI Index \\ % <=======================================
 CPFIS  & CPF Investment Scheme \\
 Produce\_Full\_SR & Produce Full Sustainability Report \\
 Full\_SR\_Assured & External Audit of Full Sustainability Report \\
 Sus\_Sec\_in\_AR & Sustainability Section in Annual Report provided \\
 \midrule
 EnergyD & Energy Disclosure \\
 EmissionsD & Emissions Disclosure \\
 WasteD & Waste Disclosure \\  
 WaterD & Water Disclosure \\
  FullD & Full Disclosure (Energy, Emissions, Waste, Water) \\
 AnyD & At Least One the Four Disclosures \\

\bottomrule[0.14em]
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par

\normalsize
\end{center}

\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It compiles without error to

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem here are the underscores (`_`) that indicate subscripts and go into mathematical mode (hence the error message with the `$`), a way to solve it is to place a backslash (`\`) in front of the underscores so `\_`